# How can I find average age of users searched by word in field MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, shell, search, aggregate

I would find average age of `"users"` from Alaska.

```
db.users.aggregate({ $match: { address:  "Alaska" } }, { $group: { _id: null, averageAge: { $avg: '$age'} } })
```

- gives no results, because field `'address'` keps full adrress of user.

Example of user:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5adf3c1544abaca147cdd34b"),
            "index" : 2,
            "guid" : "bd579f65-83a2-4966-8e33-da078369eb15",
            "isActive" : false,
            "balance" : "$3,118.30",
            "picture" : "http://placehold.it/32x32",
            "age" : 40,
            "eyeColor" : "blue",
            "name" : "Macias Shannon",
            "gender" : "male",
            "company" : "NORSUL",
            "email" : "maciasshannon@norsul.com",
            "phone" : "+1 (846) 566-2908",
            "address" : "221 Gardner Avenue, Tetherow, Virginia, 464",
            "about" : "Cupidatat ad esse ad nulla aute eiusmod veniam minim esse labore id et ipsum.\r\n",
            "greeting" : "Hello, Macias Shannon! You have 1 unread messages.",
}
```

Comment: Use `{ "$match": { "address": /Alaska/ } }` instead. See the existing answers for links to `$regex` in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! It works